# FreeSwitch WebRTC Call Termination

Tags: webrtc, freeswitch, sipml

I have FreeSwitch working with SIP Clients for

- Extension to Extension Call
- Extension to PSTN / Gateway Call
- PSTN/DID to Extension Call

I have configured WebRTC with SIPML5 clients and it is working on following scenarios

- Extension to Extension Call

for Extension to PSTN/ Gateway FreeSwitch routes call to TRUNK but its not connected.

How can I get it working ?? What is missing parameter?? I think something at bridge is required to

FS Console logs are available here

http://pastebin.com/Ye0jw37x

Comment: Just capture the sip log from invite to hangup and paste in pastebin. This info is not enough

Comment: paste the freeswitch log with more detail in pastebin